# Traefik https backend communication causes x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1 not <Container IP>

Tags: docker, ssl, traefik

Using Traefik, I have a https backend which is a docker container running webpack devserver in https mode - i.e the devserver is generating a self signed ssl certificate.

While access I get x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1 not #backendContainerIP#.

I have tried setting label '`traefik.frontend.auth.forward.tls.insecureSkipVerify=true`' on Traefik service, in hope that it would ignore the certificate validity but that didn't worked.

Here is the relevant extract from compose file:-

```
traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7.8-alpine
    command: --docker --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - 86:443
    volumes:
      - <traefikConfigFilePath>:/traefik.toml
      - <traefikAcmeFilePath>:/acme.json
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.auth.forward.tls.insecureSkipVerify=true
    networks:
      - <dockerNetwork>
    container_name: traefik
    depends_on:
      - portal

portal:
    build: <github link>
    expose:
      - <portalPort>
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=portal
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=<dockerNetwork>
      - traefik.port=<portalPort>
      - traefik.protocol=https
      - traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/
    networks:
      - <dockerNetwork>
```

Here is the relevant toml file

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address=":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
            entryPoint="https"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address=":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email=<emailaddress>
storage="acme.json"
entryPoint="https"
onHostRule=true
onDemand=false
acmeLogging=true

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: You probably need to set a SAN holding your <container ip> on the certificate.

Comment: container Ip is not static, how to go about that ? Or please let me know how to set the SAN. As all the example i see are given with domain not IP

Comment: The label `traefik.frontend.auth.forward.tls.insecureSkipVerify` is for [forward authentication](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#forward-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by adding `insecureSkipVerify= true` at the top level of toml, like this:-

> The toml file:-

```
...
insecureSkipVerify= true

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
....
```

And it was severe pain in finding that!

Comment: Ensure that it is really at the top...I had it after ```[traefikLog]```and then it is not being recognised